# Error installing newgem on linux

Tags: ruby, linux

I am trying to install newgem on my linux box (sudo gem install newgem) and i am getting the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing newgem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb install newgem
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
from extconf.rb:1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/RedCloth-4.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/RedCloth-4.0.4/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mkmf` is a Ruby module which generates Makefiles.  It is supposed to be part of the standard Ruby install, but Debian (and derivatives) split it out into the `ruby1.8-dev` package.

If you can't find `mkmf.rb` in any of the directories outputted by `ruby -e'print $:.join("\n")'`, then you should figure out what you need to install.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably caused by one of its dependencies. I don't think it needs all those dependencies anymore. If its still an issue, raise a bug at http://drnic.lighthouseapp.com/projects/18881-newgem/ and we'll see what dependencies can be ripped out.